# Как добавить SVG код в вордпресс

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, svg

У меня есть SVG анимация:

```js
var lineDrawing = anime({
  targets: '#lineDrawing path',
  strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 3000,
  delay: function(el, i) { return i * 250 },
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
```

```css
body {
  
}
 
path {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#cfc33a;
  stroke-width:9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>

<div id="lineDrawing">
 
<svg version="1.0"
 width="1024.000000pt" height="455.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 1024.000000 455.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
 
<g transform="translate(0.000000,455.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M2187 3719 c-391 -43 -725 -249 -870 -536 -69 -135 -106 -358 -87
-517 34 -289 152 -471 420 -650 155 -104 248 -142 550 -226 449 -126 483 -137
512 -169 70 -78 39 -182 -72 -245 -54 -30 -58 -31 -185 -30 -332 1 -626 101
-985 332 -52 33 -98 58 -101 54 -10 -11 -229 -675 -229 -695 0 -44 362 -242
560 -306 295 -96 601 -134 890 -112 242 19 441 71 624 163 286 144 431 331
497 643 19 88 16 334 -4 418 -53 216 -167 386 -342 512 -138 99 -244 141 -685
269 -418 123 -395 114 -438 152 -32 28 -37 37 -37 76 0 55 23 92 77 119 89 46
402 18 670 -60 76 -22 280 -102 350 -137 26 -13 54 -24 62 -24 10 0 44 93 114
308 55 169 103 317 107 329 8 27 -30 53 -190 129 -186 88 -375 148 -590 185
-130 23 -481 33 -618 18z"fill="#000"/>
<path d="M8550 2403 c-188 -32 -350 -121 -491 -271 -164 -174 -249 -385 -265
-658 -23 -376 152 -668 465 -777 158 -56 381 -48 551 18 264 104 484 362 560
660 41 161 43 376 5 520 -68 257 -267 448 -517 499 -71 15 -245 20 -308 9z
m266 -197 c158 -42 287 -174 339 -346 28 -95 30 -249 5 -369 -41 -203 -110
-340 -232 -462 -135 -136 -309 -202 -473 -178 -214 30 -364 164 -420 376 -33
122 -17 361 35 513 75 218 270 410 471 464 69 19 209 20 275 2z"/>
<path d="M4586 2368 c-13 -40 -349 -1669 -345 -1672 7 -7 209 -9 216 -3 5 5
143 649 143 668 0 3 129 9 288 12 286 5 392 16 517 53 216 63 376 291 376 538
1 190 -89 333 -246 392 -46 17 -89 19 -498 22 -360 2 -448 0 -451 -10z m784
-178 c79 -13 135 -48 164 -105 17 -32 21 -58 21 -130 0 -77 -4 -98 -27 -147
-33 -72 -102 -146 -167 -182 -83 -45 -173 -56 -457 -56 -207 0 -254 2 -254 14
0 14 118 583 125 604 6 15 497 17 595 2z"/>
<path d="M6262 2315 c-7 -36 -15 -78 -18 -95 l-6 -30 276 0 c152 0 276 -2 276
-5 0 -7 -27 -137 -179 -865 -66 -316 -121 -588 -123 -604 l-3 -29 109 1 c59 0
109 2 111 4 2 2 58 266 124 588 112 539 174 831 186 888 l5 22 275 0 c252 0
274 1 279 18 5 15 36 163 36 170 0 1 -301 2 -668 2 l-669 0 -11 -65z"/>
</g>
</svg>
  </div>
```

И у меня возникла проблема, изначальный HTML код я не могу найти, а виджет HTML код выдаёт ошибки. Вот [похожий сайт](http://Yoga-s.ru), но мне надо вместо `yoga` в правом блоке вставить SVG код.

Возможно кто-то знает, как легко найти путь к файлам?

[код на codepen](https://codepen.io/Arifulina/pen/YzXPKEO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Буду показывать на свежем примере, который сделал на сайте.
Чтобы добавить svg изображение, анимацию в Wordpress можно пойти по такому пути:

Сохранить svg код в отдельный файл.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >  
   <defs>
    <mask id="msk1">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
   <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50"  stroke= "black"  fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="157" 
   stroke-dasharray="157,0 157,0"   stroke-width="14" >
        <!-- Анимация сдвига маски реализует открывание прерывистой линии -->
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click"
  values="157,0 157,0;0,314,0,0;" fill="freeze" /> 
   </circle> 
    </mask>
   </defs> 
  <!-- Фон серого цвета    -->
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F3F3F3" />
      <!-- Путь заполнения линии прогрессбара  -->
 <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#E1E1E1" stroke-width="14"/>
      <!-- Прерывистая линия заэкранирована маской mask="url(#msk1)" -->
 <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" mask="url(#msk1)" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="314" stroke-dasharray="3.14, 3.14"  stroke="#62169D" stroke-width="12" />
          
   <text id="count" x="50%" y="50%" fill="#622B80" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">Click</text>
     
</svg>
```

Создать отдельную папку на сервере, в которую, будут складываться файлы svg

(Добавляете на сервер любым доступным вам способом)

Ссылка (вызов) Файла svg добавляется в редакторе странички wordpress с помощью `<object>`

```
<div class="alignleft">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="files/animation/dasharray/progress_dasharray.svg" width="200" height="200">
</object>
```

Ваш сервер должен поддерживать `MIME Types image/svg+xml` для этого добавьте  в файл `functions.php`   следующие строки

```
function wpcontent_svg_mime_type( $mimes = array() ) {
      $mimes['svg']  = 'image/svg+xml';
      $mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
      return $mimes;
    }
    add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpcontent_svg_mime_type' );
```

Более подробно [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1649)

После проделанных операций у вас на страничке будет работающий с анимацией файл svg.

Вот конкретный пример, где это было использовано:

[Анимации с использованием stroke-dasharray и stroke-dashoffset](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1783)

Comment: Всё сделал, как вы написали, картинка отображается по https://www.spto.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Arte.svg, но почему-то с object анимация не работает((

Comment: @ДенисПетров Отлично, уже есть прогресс. Нет анимации потому что в вашем файле Arte.svg нет команд анимации. В примере на кодепен у вас была анимация в CSS/ Перенесите её внутрь файла SVG между тегами `<style>`  </style>

Comment: @ДенисПетров добавил ответ по вашему комментарию

Answer (score 3):

Ответ по вопросу в [комментарии @ДенисПетров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079924/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-svg-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81/1079958#comment1856973_1079958):

> Всё сделал, как вы написали, картинка отображается по
>   spto.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Arte.svg, но почему-то с object
>   анимация не работает

Анимация не работает потому, что внутри вашего файла `Arte.svg` нет команды анимации.

Самый простой путь решения, добавить команды анимации CSS внутрь файла SVG между тегами `<style> ... </style>`.

Я доработал немного ваш файл взятый с [codepen](https://codepen.io/Arifulina/pen/YzXPKEO).

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="1024.000000pt" height="455.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 1024.000000 455.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<style>
 body {
  
}
 
path {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#cfc33a;
  stroke-width:20;
  stroke-dasharray:14744;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  animation: draw 10s infinite forwards;
}
@keyframes draw {
0%,100% {stroke-dashoffset:14744;}
50% {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
</style>
 
<g transform="translate(0.000000,455.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M2187 3719 c-391 -43 -725 -249 -870 -536 -69 -135 -106 -358 -87
-517 34 -289 152 -471 420 -650 155 -104 248 -142 550 -226 449 -126 483 -137
512 -169 70 -78 39 -182 -72 -245 -54 -30 -58 -31 -185 -30 -332 1 -626 101
-985 332 -52 33 -98 58 -101 54 -10 -11 -229 -675 -229 -695 0 -44 362 -242
560 -306 295 -96 601 -134 890 -112 242 19 441 71 624 163 286 144 431 331
497 643 19 88 16 334 -4 418 -53 216 -167 386 -342 512 -138 99 -244 141 -685
269 -418 123 -395 114 -438 152 -32 28 -37 37 -37 76 0 55 23 92 77 119 89 46
402 18 670 -60 76 -22 280 -102 350 -137 26 -13 54 -24 62 -24 10 0 44 93 114
308 55 169 103 317 107 329 8 27 -30 53 -190 129 -186 88 -375 148 -590 185
-130 23 -481 33 -618 18z" fill="#000"/>
<path d="M8550 2403 c-188 -32 -350 -121 -491 -271 -164 -174 -249 -385 -265
-658 -23 -376 152 -668 465 -777 158 -56 381 -48 551 18 264 104 484 362 560
660 41 161 43 376 5 520 -68 257 -267 448 -517 499 -71 15 -245 20 -308 9z
m266 -197 c158 -42 287 -174 339 -346 28 -95 30 -249 5 -369 -41 -203 -110
-340 -232 -462 -135 -136 -309 -202 -473 -178 -214 30 -364 164 -420 376 -33
122 -17 361 35 513 75 218 270 410 471 464 69 19 209 20 275 2z"/>
<path d="M4586 2368 c-13 -40 -349 -1669 -345 -1672 7 -7 209 -9 216 -3 5 5
143 649 143 668 0 3 129 9 288 12 286 5 392 16 517 53 216 63 376 291 376 538
1 190 -89 333 -246 392 -46 17 -89 19 -498 22 -360 2 -448 0 -451 -10z m784
-178 c79 -13 135 -48 164 -105 17 -32 21 -58 21 -130 0 -77 -4 -98 -27 -147
-33 -72 -102 -146 -167 -182 -83 -45 -173 -56 -457 -56 -207 0 -254 2 -254 14
0 14 118 583 125 604 6 15 497 17 595 2z"/>
<path d="M6262 2315 c-7 -36 -15 -78 -18 -95 l-6 -30 276 0 c152 0 276 -2 276
-5 0 -7 -27 -137 -179 -865 -66 -316 -121 -588 -123 -604 l-3 -29 109 1 c59 0
109 2 111 4 2 2 58 266 124 588 112 539 174 831 186 888 l5 22 275 0 c252 0
274 1 279 18 5 15 36 163 36 170 0 1 -301 2 -668 2 l-669 0 -11 -65z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Загрузил файл SVG на сервер и вызываю его с помощью `<object>`

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/Arte-css3.svg" width="470" height="470" >
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

Работоспособность анимации файла SVG можно проверить загрузив в адресную строку браузера - `https://svg-art.ru/files/Arte-css3.svg`

**Если вы планируете использовать svg файл, как анимированную картинку лого, то есть не планируется интерактивности: наведение, клик курсора и т.д, то можно использовать для добавления SVG тег `<img>`**

```html
<image src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Arte-css3.svg">
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё получилось!

Comment: @ДенисПетров я рад за вас!